# 'cin' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I run my code and it gives an error  'cin' was not declared in this scope
My code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int m,a,b,c,d,e,f;
main()
{
    cin>>m>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f;

    double g=a%b;
    double h=c%d;
    double k=e%f;
if (g<h && g<k){
    int i=g;
}

if (h<g && h<k) {
    int i=h;
}

if (k<g && k<h) {
    int i=g;
}
double s=i*m;
cout<<s;
}
```

`

i think i wrote it right,help me

Comment: First of all, [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problem, `cin` is in the `std` namespace, so you need to use `std::cin`. As taught by any decent [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), tutorial or class.

Comment: or `using namespace std;`

Comment: @wojand Except [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Your current usage of C++ will just give you bad habits if you continue on.

Comment: And by the way, global variables (outside of any functions) should be avoided as well. And you need to read up more on scope. When you do `i * m` there's no such variable named `i`. And learn how to give your variables meaningful names.

Comment: Please do not use "that website" to teach you c++. It'll teach you awful habits and will _not_ make you a good programmer. You need a decent C++ book.

Answer (score 4):

Use C++ standard library includes

```
#include <iostream>
```

then

`std::cin`

and

`std::cout`

If you do this, then you are writing portable and easy to read C++.

Even better, check that the data have been successfully read:

```
if (std::cin >> m >> a >> b>> c>> d>> e >> f){
    // success - go on from here
}
```